# Calculate first ul li height of each and apply on second ul li respectively

Tags: jquery, height, html-lists

I have two lists and I want to calculate the first the height of the `li` in the  first `ul` and apply it to the second. This is what I tried:

```
<ul class="first">
    <li class="">item1</li>
    <li class="">item1</li>
    <li class="">item1</li>
    <li class="">item1</li>
    <li class="">item1</li>
    <li class="">item1</li> 
    <li class="">item1</li>
    <li class="">item1</li> 
    <li class="">item1</li>
    <li class="">item1</li>
</ul>

<ul class="second">
    <li class="">item1</li>
    <li class="">item1</li>
    <li class="">item1</li>
    <li class="">item1</li>
    <li class="">item1</li>
    <li class="">item1</li> 
    <li class="">item1</li>
    <li class="">item1</li> 
    <li class="">item1</li>
    <li class="">item1</li>
</ul>
```

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    jQuery('.first ul li').each(function(){
        var ht = jQuery.makeArray($(this).height());
    });

    jQuery('.second ul li').each(function(){
        $(this).css('height',ht);
    }); 
}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Are you trying to make both `ul` elements the same height, or are you trying to make matching `li` the same height, so the first `li` would both be 100px, the second be 50px and so on.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    console.log('ready');
    var ht=[];
    $('.first li').each(function(index){
        ht[index]=$(this).height();
        console.log(ht[index]);
    });

    $('.second li').each(function(index){
        $(this).css('height',ht[index]);
    });    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change below code and it's working fine.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.first li').each(function(index){
        $('.second').find('li').eq(index).css('height', $(this).css('height'));
    });
});
```